# Number of arrangements with no consecutive letter the same

Tags: php, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

This question is related to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048646/number-of-arrangements-with-no-consecutive-letter-the-same-without-using-jair). I am trying to get the following count programmatically to verify whether my mathematics is right.

> How many arrangements of the letters in the word PQRDDDEEEEFFFFF have
>   no consecutive letter the same?

How to determine this count using a php program?

**My approach**

1. generated all possible permutations using heap's algorithm and stored in an array *(used heap's algorithm as it is found faster)*
2. removed all duplicates using array_unique function
3. Iterated through the array, identified the strings where adjacent letters are same using regexp /(.)\1/ and copied the strings where no adjacent letters are same to a new array.
4. The new array has the list of elements which is required.

My approach is working fine. But, for large strings (strings above 10 characters), memory issues are coming due to the large number of permutations and so the program does not work.

Is there any alternative approach to determine this programmatically?

**Note:**

I am looking for the count only and not the list of strings

Comment: PHP may not be your best option for something like this

Comment: @scottevans93, u suggest any other language to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some Python that's much more efficient than your method, though still exponential (sorry, don't know PHP):

```
from collections import Counter


def instancekey(letters):
    return tuple(sorted(Counter(letters).values()))


memo = {}


def permcount(letters):
    if not letters:
        return 1
    key = instancekey(letters)
    count = memo.get(key)
    if count is None:
        count = 0
        for letter, lettercount in Counter(letters).items():
            rest = letters
            for i in range(lettercount):
                j = rest.find(letter)
                rest = rest[:j] + rest[j + 1:]
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    count += permcount(rest)
                else:
                    count -= permcount(rest)
        memo[key] = count
    return count
```

There are two ideas here. The first is to perform the count recursively via inclusion-exclusion. For each letter in the input, we accumulate the number of possibilities that begin with that letter. Naively, it's enough to count the possibilities for the remaining letters, but this doesn't enforce the constraint that the first two letters are equal. Thus we apply a correction -- subtract the number of possibilities where two letters are deleted. This correction itself requires a correction, whereupon we arrive at the [inclusion-exclusion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

The second idea is to use memoization to cut down significantly on the number of function evaluations. Given a word like `PQRDDDEEEEFFFFF`, we count

```
P: 1
Q: 1
R: 1
D: 3
E: 4
F: 5
```

and then drop the letters (because they don't matter) and sort the values:

```
1,1,1,3,4,5.
```

Comment: thanks, it is working fine. executed at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMampGYWJfYmppdDA, tested with various values. This is faster also.

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine as a graph problem. The graph would have nodes for each letter in your set "PQRDDDEEEEFFFFF" and do not allow self-loop paths back to the same letter or between nodes that represent the same letter. You would then enumerate all non-cyclic paths of length 15 through your graph. This should significantly reduce the memory footprint of your code and you would not generate any "words" with consecutive letters that need to be discarded. With a quick google search I found a few different graph traversal algorithms in php available online. You could tweak one to your purposes fairly quickly.

For a significant performance enhancement you could employ memoization strategies. i.e. starting from one 'F' the permutations from the other 'F' nodes are identical and the same is true of sub-paths. There are some knight's tour algorithms with memoization  that can also be adapted to this problem well.

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

Python is one of the most popular open source (free) languages for working with the large and complicated datasets needed for Big Data. It has become very popular in recent years because it is both flexible and relatively easy to learn. Like most popular open source software it also has a large and active community dedicated to improving the product and making it popular with new users. A free Code Academy course will take you through the basics in 13 hours.

Sources:

http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/ten-top-languages-for-crunching-big-data
https://www.continuum.io/why-python

Answer (score 0):

The *pure* method is to brute force it. Just count in base N, where N is the number of distinct letters. The number of places needed in the base N number, is just the total number of letters. Then apply the constraints for the number of each letter allowed and not having two consecutive the same.

It's not pretty and not fast, but it will give correct answers.

Here it is in PHP:

```
$letters = 'PQRDDDEEEEFFFFF';

$letter_counts = CountLetters($letters);

echo CountCombinations($letter_counts);

function CountLetters($letters) {
    $letter_counts = array();
    foreach (str_split($letters) as $letter) {
        if (isset($letter_counts[$letter])) {
            $letter_counts[$letter]++;
        } else {
            $letter_counts[$letter] = 1;
        }
    }
    return array_values($letter_counts);
}

function CountCombinations($allowable) {
    $max = count($allowable) - 1;
    $total_places = 0;
    for ($index = 0; $index <= $max; $index++) {
        $total_places += $allowable[$index];
    }

    $counter = array_fill(0, $total_places, 0);

    $combinations = 0;
    do {
        $ok = true;

        // count the number of each character in this combination
        $bins = array_fill(0, $max + 1, 0);
        for ($index = 0; $index < $total_places; $index++) {
            $bins[$counter[$index]]++;
        }

        // ensure the counts match the number allowable for each
        for ($index = 0; $index <= $max; $index++) {
            if ($bins[$index] != $allowable[$index]) {
                $ok = false;
                break;
            }

        }

        // ensure that no two consecutive are the same
        if ($ok) {
            for ($index = 0; $index <= ($total_places - 2); $index++) {
                if ($counter[$index] == $counter[$index + 1]) {
                    $ok = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($ok) {
            $combinations++;
        }

        // find the next combination (i.e. count in base N)
        for ($index = 0; $index <= ($total_places - 1); $index++) {
            $counter[$index] = $counter[$index] + 1;
            if ($counter[$index] <= $max) {
                break;
            } else {
                $counter[$index] = 0;
            }
        }
    } while ($index < $total_places);

    return $combinations;
}
```